# C# Block mouse movement

Tags: c#, mouse, block

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to Make the Mouse Freeze c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996382/how-to-make-the-mouse-freeze-c)
>   [How can I block keyboard and mouse input in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586547/how-can-i-block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-c)

I'm making a mouse macro program, and I already have the core mostly worked out. It would be nice, though, if I could temporarily block the user from using the mouse while the macro is playing... is this possible in C#?

---

**EDIT**

This code works perfectly for me:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool BlockInput(bool block);

    public static void FreezeMouse()
    {
        BlockInput(true);
    }

    public static void ThawMouse()
    {
        BlockInput(false);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds pretty malicious to me.

Comment: You can display a message in big bold red letters "Stop moving the mouse!"

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I wouldn't want them to interfere with the playing macro. I would have a keyboard shortcut to stop the macro and re-enable the mouse.

Comment: @Remus: lol! Thats one way to do it

Comment: [Block input in C# (stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586547/how-can-i-block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-c)

Comment: Consider though that frozen mouse is immediately associated by user with frozen app and give a very bad user experience. Perhaps you can hide the cursor instead, while inside your application's form: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide.aspx

Comment: Well then the users couldn't see the cursor playing out the macro...